# Spring Boot application.properties not able to fetch value from another property file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, deployment

In my spring boot project, I have two properties file application.properties and values.properties.
location is as follows:
my--project -> src -> main -> resource -> application.properties
my-project -> var -> local -> values.properties

application.properties content

```
common.rest.client.clientId=${token_service_client_id}
```

values.properties content

```
token_service_client_id=askfjltirklajklioe
```

I am able to build the project but while running it, its throwing error

```
can not resolve placeholder  ${token_service_client_id}
```

Is there any way to include values.properties in either in the build or pass it as an argument to

> java -jar my-project.jar

command so that application.properties can read it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use --spring.config.location to specify the location of your properties file while running the jar file

e.g: java -jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,file:/var/local/values.properties